# Animation not repeating

Tags: android-animation

I am trying to get the text view to zoomin/out 4 times one by one. It works only once and then just dies.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AnimationListener {
    Animation zoomin, zoomout;
    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    zoomin = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,
                            R.anim.zoomin);
                    zoomin.setAnimationListener(MainActivity.this);
                    zoomout = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,
                            R.anim.zoomout);
                    text.setAnimation(zoomin);
                    text.setAnimation(zoomout);

                    text.startAnimation(zoomin);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        text.startAnimation(zoomout);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
text.startAnimation(zoonout);
```

to

```
text.startAnimation(zoomin);
```

Hope it helps u. Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote Siddharth. I'm Happy that the solution works for you. Have a nice day.